# Linq multiple aggregates and max

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with CarID, ServiceType, ServiceDate, MilesLastService.
I want to retrieve the ServiceDate and MilesLastService of the last record for a particular car of a certain ServiceType.  How would the linq query look.

in my head the query looks like this:

```
Max(select ServiceDate, MilesLastService
Where (CarID = 50 && ServiceType == "TransmissionService")
```

I was trying something like this, but I can't figure it out

```
var d2 = from m in db.Table<ServiceRecords>()
where m.CarID == carid
group m by new { m.ServiceDate, m.Milage };
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Following query will select last record for each service type for given car:

```
from sr in db.Table<ServiceRecords>()
where sr.CarID == id
group sr by sr.ServiceType into g
select g.OrderByDescending(sr => sr.ServiceDate).First();
```

If you want to get only miles and date, then

```
from sr in db.Table<ServiceRecords>()
where sr.CarID == id
group sr by sr.ServiceType into g
let lastRecord = g.OrderByDescending(sr => sr.ServiceDate).First()
select new {
   lastRecord.MilesLastService,
   lastRecord.ServiceDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ like below:

```
var d2 = (from m in db.Table<ServiceRecords>()
          where m.CarID == carid && m.ServiceType == "TransmissionService"
          select new {ServiceDate = m.ServiceDate, MilesLastService = m.MilesLastService})
         .OrderBy(x => x.ServiceDate)
         .Last();
var milesLastService = d2.MilesLastService;
var serviceDate = d2.ServiceDate;
```

I have ordered the retrieved list using `ServiceDate`.